# spec.type must be defined in react-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I'm trying to make a Trello clone using React  react-dnd.
**Just by entering the code below I get the error**

```
 const [{ isDragging }, dragRef] = useDrag({
    item: { type: "CARD" },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
    }),
  });
```

I get the following error

**spec.type must be defined**

```
invariant
C:/Users/lucca/Documents/GitHub/2B-task/src/index.ts:28
 25  |   );
  26 | } else {
  27 |   let argIndex = 0;
> 28 |   error = new Error(
     | ^  29 |     format.replace(/%s/g, function() {
  30 |       return args[argIndex++];
  31 |     })
```

Answer (score 13):

**FIX:**

In version ^14 of React DnD the API format changed. The type is now decoupled from item:

```
// Pre-v14
useDrag({
   // item defined here to get a type
   item: { type: BOX } },
   // ...but the actual item is created here
   begin: () => ({ id })
})

// v14
useDrag({
   // type is now listed by itself, not inside of item
   type: BOX,
   item: () => ({id})
})
```

**TLDR:**

Documentation on this:
https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/releases/tag/v14.0.0

This should work on all recent React versions. My versions are:

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dnd": "^15.0.2",
"react-dnd-html5-backend": "^15.0.2",
```

Answer (score 6):

Here `type` should be passed as a prop of useDrag. Please make sure you are passing the same type `CARD` in `useDrop` as well in `accept`. You can find more references [here](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/hooks-overview#basic-example).

```
const [{ isDragging }, dragRef] = useDrag({
    type: "CARD",
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
    }),
  });

 const [collectedProps, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: "CARD",
    collect: (monitor: any) => { ... },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As in another answer given, you need to make the type a property of the useDrag object.

```
const [{isDragging}, drag] = useDrag({
        type: "CARD",
        collect: monitor => ({
          isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging()
        })
      })
```

Comment: Hi Adylbek, I've updated your answer to make it a little more clear what the changes are.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after react-dnd upgrade. Working again after Rollback.

Opening an issue with React-dnd might help to find the root cause.

Edit: Change was made for 14.0 release : https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/releases/tag/v14.0.0

Comment: Can you please mention that version?

Comment: Edited my answer. "type" has now to be defined outside of "Item". Updated and fixed my code.

Comment: I had this issue - was using react-dnd^11.1.3, then ran an 'npm i' to reinstall packages and react-dnd was updated to 14.0.2. This caused the same 'spec.type must be defined' issue

Answer (score 1):

Change version
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dnd": "^11.1.3",
"react-dnd-html5-backend": "^11.1.3",

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions with just a code snippet. [Check this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write an answer.